# Processing form with multiple checkboxes using Symfony form component

Tags: php, forms, symfony, silex

As part of a Silex application I have a form with multiple checkboxes so that a user can choose one or more options from a list. I import the `symfony/form` component to handle the backend form processing.

I'm writing the HTML for displaying the form manually as it's displayed in a table and I'm not sure how to make the `form_widget` helper achieve that (it's fine when I just want a form displaying 'as is').

The code for each checkbox is (`plan.id` is a unique ID for each plan):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="plans[]" value="{{ plan.id }}">
```

The part I'm struggling with is how to process the data. At the moment the code within my route is:

```
$form_builder = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder(FormType::class);

foreach ($plans as $plan) {
  $form_builder->add("plans[]", CheckboxType::class);
}

$form = $form_builder->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

$data = $form->getData();
```

However, when I submit the form I get the following error:

> The name "plans[]" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":").

I've never had a problem processing forms with elements named `foo[]` without using a framework. Is it possible to achieve the same result with Symfony forms or do I need to rethink how I am doing this?

The relevant versions from `composer show` are:

```
silex/silex               v2.0.4             The PHP micro-framework based
symfony/form              v3.2.2             Symfony Form Component
symfony/validator         v3.2.2             Symfony Validator Component
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to use collections.

Comment: What is the target entity you want to save these checkboxes for?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'target entity'. I'm not saving the checkboxes, they are used to decide which documents (plans) to use in a report which is generated on the fly and so don't need to be saved anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get any of the proposed answers/comments to work, despite many attempts.

In the end I simply added each checkbox with a unique name ("plans_" + plan.id), rather than trying to create an array of checkboxes with the same name. It doesn't feel as clean as processing an array, and I've no idea why this is so much hassle in Symfony, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [collections](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) for a set of checkboxes.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
// ...

$builder->add('plans', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => CheckboxType::class,
    // these options are passed to each "checkbox" type
    'entry_options'  => array(
        'attr'      => array('class' => 'check-box')
    ),
));
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense I guess. How do I add the individual checkboxes to the form though? At the moment the form processing results in `$form->isValid()` being `false` but `$form->getErrors()->count()` is `0`.

Comment: Add individuals as always - `$form_builder->add("indivname", CheckboxType::class);`

Comment: I think I need more code to debug validation behaviour. Well, does it create a right form with `name="plans[]"` checkboxes?

Comment: No, it doesn't create a form with multiple `name="plans[]"` checkboxes.